# Change background colour of knitr::kable headers

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I need to change the background colour of the headers of a table printed with knitr::kable. I can use `kableExtra::column_spec` to change the background of a whole column, but it doesn't affect the header row:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)) %>% 
  column_spec(1, background = "yellow")
```

[image]

**Wanted outcome:** 
A `kable` output where the header of column `a` has a yellow background (and the rest of the table a white background).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using `cell_spec`.  For example,

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)
names(df)[1] <- cell_spec(names(df)[1], background = "yellow")
kable(df, escape = FALSE)
```

This doesn't display automatically in RStudio for me; you need to pipe it through a `kableExtra` function to do that.  For example, this pipe does nothing except to mark the table to display.

```
kable(df, escape = FALSE) %>% column_spec(1)
```

will display

[image: screenshot]

Another way to do it is to set the whole column including the header to yellow, then set the non-header part to the inherited colour.  You do that like this:

```
kable(df) %>% 
  column_spec(1, background = "yellow", include_thead = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(1, background = "inherit")
```

This one ends up with messy HTML, but the spacing looks a bit better:

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 6):

```
kable(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)) %>% 
  row_spec(0, background = "yellow")
```

Comment: This makes all of the column names yellow. OP wants only specific column as yellow.